# On Button click show list...in sencha

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

```
Ext.application({
  launch: function () {

    Ext.define("User", {
      extend: "Ext.data.Model",
      config: {
        fields: [{name: "title", type: "string"}]
      }
    });

    var myStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
      model: "User",
      proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        url : "http://www.imdb.com/xml/find?json=1&nr=1&tt=on&q=twilight",
        reader: {
          type: "json",
          rootProperty: "title_popular"
        }
      },
      autoLoad: true
    });

    var view = Ext.Viewport.add({
      xtype: 'navigationview',
      //we only give it one item by default, which will be the only item in the 'stack' when it loads
      items: [{
        xtype:'formpanel',
        title: 'SEARCH IMDB MOVIES ',
        padding: 10,
        items: [{
          xtype: 'fieldset',
          title: 'Search Movies from IMDB',
          items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name : 'Movie Search',
            label: 'Search Movie'
          }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Submit',
            handler: function () {
              view.push({
                //this one also has a title
                title: 'List of Movies',
                padding: 10,
                //once again, this view has one button
                items: [{
                  xyz.show();
                }]
              });
            }
          }]
        }]
      }]
    });

    var xyz = new Ext.create("Ext.List", {
      fullscreen: true,
      store: myStore,
      itemTpl: "{title}"
    });
  }
});
```

error is with xyz.show();
it will work properly if i remove xyz.show();
but i want to show list after clicking on buttton
This is a navigation view on click of button i want to show list

Comment: Have you tried it with `var xyz = ...` before `var view = ...`?

Comment: yes.... but it is also not working.. and i also want to know how to getvalue of textfield which we set and then click on submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your xyz list as follows:

```
var xyz = new Ext.create("Ext.List", {
  //this one also has a title
  title: 'List of Movies',
  padding: 10,
  xtype:'xyz',
  alias:'xyz',
  hidden:true,
  fullscreen: true,
  store: myStore,
  itemTpl: "{title}"
});
```

Then just below it write

```
view.add(xyz);
```

Then in your handler

```
handler: function () {
    xyz.show();
}
```

Not tested but it should work with possible adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
handler: function () {
  view.push({
    //this one also has a title
    title: 'List of Movies',
    padding: 10,
    //once again, this view has one button
    items: [
      xyz
    ]
  });
}
```